# How to store records entered in windows.prompt in mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am using `window.prompt` to enter the data (email address) in the field.

Now I want to store the value entered in the field in MySQL database...  I am using PHP as my server-side language.

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    var time, rate, remainingTime;
    clearTimeout(stopPlayTimer);
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
      time = player.getCurrentTime();
      // Add .4 of a second to the time in case it's close to the current time
      // (The API kept returning ~9.7 when hitting play after stopping at 10s)
      if (time + .4 < stopPlayAt) {
        rate = player.getPlaybackRate();
        remainingTime = (stopPlayAt - time) / rate;
        stopPlayTimer = setTimeout(pauseVideo, remainingTime * 1000);
        var pvalue=window.prompt("Enter Email");
        document.getElementById("abc").value=pvalue;


      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Use AJAX to save the data.

Comment: @senz use a library that knows how to connect to mysql and insert the data. https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql

Comment: I know it may seem obvious, but sanitize your input both for security and data consistency reasons. (to avoid exploits and to be sure that people has entered data in email format.)

Comment: Go to php.net and look up how to do that or find a tutorial- there are plenty.  Then when you have some specific problem doing what you want post the code here and ask a question.

Comment: @K Neeraj Lal, could you please help me with code?